# What is the vaahan (mount) of Lord Hanuman?

Tags: hanuman, animals, vahana

Does Lord Hanuman have a mount (vahana) like all the other Gods? I got this doubt when I have seen a *camel* before Hanuman in a temple like Nandi before Lord Shiva.I searched the internet about this and got [this](https://premaarpan.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/camel-the-vahana-of-lord-hanuman/) answer but not satisfied by it. Is this true?
 It is nowhere mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana. Is this mentioned in any other scripture? If so please explain with sources.

Comment: Am not Sure, but hanuman not have a mount like other Gods,himself he can beat the speed of Vayu, because of the boon he got from the Vayudev.

Comment: In which temple did you see camel?

Comment: @TheDestroyer [Shree Tadbund Veeranjaneya Swamy Temple](http://www.tadbundveeranjaneyaswamy.org/veeranjaneya-swamy-deities.htm). This is a swayambhu Hanuman temple near Secunderabad. Click the link and visit temple website.

Comment: It is stated that the life history of Lord Hanuman is written by Sage Parasara in Parasara Samhita in which there are stories of birth of Hanuman, stories of devotees of Him, MARRIAGE AND MOUNT of Hanuman is also stated. I could not find it on web with english translation but in sanskrit. If anyone are scholar in sanskrit, I provide you the link [here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskritupload/parAsharasamhitAhanupatcharitra1.pdf).

Comment: @SreeCharan Can i know legend of that temple? The official website doesn't give any info on His manifestation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vaahan (mount) of Hanuman is **Ushtra** i.e,, a camel. This is mentioned in Hanumat suktham, Hanuman mangalashasanam and other stotras.
The reason why Hanuma chose camel as his mount is:

- Generally camels are found in desret areas where land is filled with sand dunes. The feet of camel are perfect to move on sand dunes.
- As mentioned above in other answer by Rickross. Hanuman is **Pampaatheerthavihaari** meaning who is fond of roaming on the banks of the river Pampa. It is because he met Shree Rama for the first time there.
- Hanuman is also fond of doing pradakshina to [RamaSethu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_Bridge) which he along with Vanarasena helped ShreeRam to rescue Sita and kill Ravana.
  As camel is fit for travelling on sand, Hanuman chose it as His mount. 

  It is also mentioned in Parasara Samhita that he rode a camel and gave darshan to many of his devotees like somadatta, Dhwajadatta on a camel.

Also the Dhwaja (flag) of Hanuman is a camel.

Source of this answer is *Parasara Samhita*, [Hanumat suktham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iKvWFMusPg) and answer to a question by [Dr.Annadanam Chidambara Shastry](http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?page_id=2) a scholar who did research on the life history of Hanuman. Watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wR9Rf2oUZ0).

Answer (score 2):

**Camel** is Vahana for Sri Hanuman.

The Hanumat Sooktam mentions him as riding one viz:**usthraa roodha**(one who is riding on a camel).

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?If u think camel is not the vahana then please post ur answer.